# Sending array parameter to web service method

Tags: php, python, web-services, yii, soappy

I've a PHP SOAP web service method using Yii, here's the code:

```
    /**
     * return list of cities
     * @param array $attributes filter for City
     * @return array
     * @soap
     */
    public function getCities($attributes=array()) {
        $result = City::model()->findAllByAttributes($attributes);
        return CJSON::decode(CJSON::encode($result));
    }
```

and how to send the $attributes parameter using Python as client ?
I'm using SOAPpy, and this is my current code without $attribute parameter:

```
from SOAPpy import WSDL

WSDLURL = 'http://yii-soap.lan/service'
server = WSDL.Proxy(WSDLURL)
print server.getCities()
```

Comment: First you should find out, how to hit this web service by some rest client like poster plugin for Firefox and then implement the same in python.

Comment: @Hemc how does this related to rest ?
this is a SOAP service

Comment: oho ,sorry i mean SOAP client.